# Pourquoi « grande dame » et pas « grande madame »?

Tags: histoire, société

Dans l'histoire de la France le terme « grande dame » a été utilisé pour référer aux femmes de naissance et il ne s'agit pas de ce terme dans ma question mais du terme tel qu'utilisé de nos jours et qui, chose pas très surprenante au vu de l'avènement de l'émancipation féminine et ses effet positifs qui ont caractérisé le siècle passé, est un terme utilisé [plus souvent](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grande+dame&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrande%20dame%3B%2Cc0) depuis une cinquantaine d'années.

Pourquoi dit-on « grande dame » et pas « grande madame » comme équivalent féminin de « grand monsieur »?

Comment: Hypothèse : Possiblement parce que *grande madame* (comme *grande mademoiselle*) ont, dans l'histoire, désigné des personnes en particulier.

Answer (score 4):

*Madame* utilisé avec un article (*la madame* ou *une madame*) est rare et le plus souvent péjoratif (ou enfantin) alors que *une dame*, *la dame* sont plutôt respectueux.

Pour garder le sens de *grand monsieur*, le substantif *dame* est donc employé.

On retrouve cette asymétrie dans :

- Dis bonjour au monsieur / dis bonjour à la dame
- Il y a un monsieur qui vous attend - il y a une dame qui vous attend

D'autre part, contrairement à *madame*, *monsieur* n'est plus vraiment dissociable, le mot *sieur* étant plus que désuet.

Comment: J'ajouterais que *la/une madame* peut aussi "sonner" comme du langage enfantin.