# Origine de l'asymétrie entre « dame » et « monsieur »

Tags: possessif, évolution

Une [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/31873/3177) que j'ai posée précédemment (Pourquoi « grande dame » et pas « grande madame »?) produit la [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/31879/3177) suivante;

> L'utilisation avec un article est rare, voire péjorative, donc pour fournir un équivalent féminin de « grand monsieur » on a eu recours au mot « dame ».

Cela ne tient pas compte du fait que l'on trouve « grande dame » depuis à peu près 1760 et « grand monsieur » n'est trouvé que légèrement plus tard et reste [**toujours beaucoup moins utilisé**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grand+monsieur%2Cgrande+dame%2C+grand+homme&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrand%20monsieur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrande%20dame%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrand%20homme%3B%2Cc0) que « grande dame ». On pourrait suspecter qu'il y a eu un glissement de l'ancienne acception du terme vers la nouvelle, possiblement dans un contexte de préservation de la séparation entre « ma » et « dame », contexte  qui ne peut être qu'obscur. Cela mis à part, la réponse qui a été trouvée ramène la question initiale à la suivante;

pourquoi le possessif a été agglutiné pour « sieur » (monsieur) dans tous les contextes  et pas pour « dame » (madame)? Cela revient à se demander pourquoi le mot « sieur » a été perdu mais pas le mot « dame ».

Comment: Peut être à cause de l'homophonie avec *scieur* ...

Answer (score 2):

Il est important de noter que cette asymétrie est de vieille origine - le mot *sieur* en [*monsieur*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Monsieur) est une forme oblique dérivée de *seigneur* qui est lui-même issu du latin *senior*, tandis que le mot *dame* en [*madame*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Madame) est venu directement du latin *domina*.

À cet égard, on peut voir que le congruent de *madame* se présente comme *monseigneur*, donc le congruent de *grande dame* devient *grand seigneur*, un mot d'usage si fréquent dans l'histoire qu'on le trouve même comme expression en anglais.

(Voir [l'étymologie du mot *seigneur*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/seigneur) où l'on trouve que  *grand seigneur* est utilisé dès la 17ème siécle)

Comment: Les deux termes (monsieur, madame) existent depuis le moyen-âge (significations variées depuis), et donc lorsque l'expression « grand monsieur » a commencé à être utilisé le mot « madame » était disponible pour permettre d'utiliser l'équivalent « grande madame »; au lieu de cela, cet équivalent est « grande dame »; la question est « pourquoi? » ou plutôt, « Y aurait-il une raison révélatrice d'un certain courant d'esprit, d'un état de chose historique intéressant qui ait été la cause de ce choix particulier? ». Vos  précisions, bien qu'utiles, ne  constituent pas une réponse.

Comment: Votre question et subséquent commentaire présuppose une rélation d'équivalence entre *monsieur* et *madame*, qui, comme ma réponse montre, n'est pas le cas d'un point de vue grammatique (nominatif vs. oblique).